# SQL query issues: Not all records retrieved from multiple tables in a mysql datatbase

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So i have a 3 tables. A **match** table with records of the two teams playing against each other.

`mchID   mchTeama       mchTeamb       mchScorea   mchScoreb

1       Cathedral      Holy Trinity     3           0

2       St. Andrew's   Immanuel 
                       Church           2           0`

I also have **teams** table with records of all teams participating

`tmID    tmName

1       Cathedral
2       Holy Trinity Lekki`

and the **players** table

`plyID  plyName  plyPosition  teamID
 1      Michael  Defense      2
 2      Peter    Forward      1
 3      Chukwudi Forward      1
 4      Johnson  Midfield     2
 5      John     Forward      2
 6      Samuel   keeper       1`

On my html page, i have a form with multiple drop downs that gets populated from the players table based on a series of queries to all three tables based on the match ID passed to the page.

```
$colname_matchrf = "-1";
    if (isset($_GET['mchrf'])) {
      $colname_matchrf = $_GET['mchrf'];
    }

    $query_match = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE mchID = $colname_matchrf";
    $result_match = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $query_match);
    $row_match = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_match);
    $totalRows_match = mysqli_num_rows($result_match);

    $matchTeamA =  $row_match['mchTeama'];
    $matchTeamB =  $row_match['mchTeamb'];


    $query_lineupteama = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE tmName = '".$matchTeamA. "'";
    $result_lineupteama = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $query_lineupteama);
    $row_lineupteama = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_lineupteama);
    $totalRows_lineupteama = mysqli_num_rows($result_lineupteama);

    $matchTeamaID =  $row_lineupteama['tmID'];

    $query_playersa = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE teamID = $matchTeamaID AND plyPosition != 'Coach' AND plyPosition != 'Assistant Coach'";
    $result_playersa = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $query_playersa);
    $row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersa);
    $totalRows_playersa = mysqli_num_rows($result_playersa);


    $query_lineupteamb = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE tmName = '".$matchTeamB. "'";
    $result_lineupteamb = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $query_lineupteamb);
    $row_lineupteamb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_lineupteamb);
    $totalRows_lineupteamb = mysqli_num_rows($result_lineupteamb);

    $matchTeambID =  $row_lineupteamb['tmID'];  

    $query_playersb = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE teamID = $matchTeambID AND plyPosition != 'Coach' AND plyPosition != 'Assistant Coach'";
    $result_playersb = mysqli_query($connBiscup, $query_playersb);
    $row_playersb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersb);
    $totalRows_playersb = mysqli_num_rows($result_playersb);
```

This is the form drop down sample

```
<?php
    while ($row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersa)) {
        $playersa[] = $row_playersa;
    }
?>
<div class="std_textbox2">
  <select name="captaina" class="input-field-login3" id="captaina" tabindex="1">
    <option selected="Selected">--Select Player--</option>
      <?php foreach ($playersa as $playera): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $playera['plyName']; ?>"><?php echo $playera['plyName']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

So the issue is this, the forms drop down gets populated but not with all the records I expect to be there. For instance the drop down for the `team A` should have all players from the **players** table who have their **teamID** as **1**. But what I get is just some of the records not all. 
Any help as to whats wrong would be **highly** appreciated.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: A little sensible database design would work wonders

Comment: @MarcB I would clean up the form entries before storing in the database. My issue now is in the queries i think.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Don't understand. Please explain.

Comment: so? you're still using $_GET data directly in your queries, so no matter how much cleaning you when you do store the data, the moment you try to RETRIEVE any of that data you can get totally pwn3d.

Comment: you want to fetch all player against the team id of teams ?

Comment: select p.plyName,p.teamID from players p LEFT JOIN teams t  where t.tmID=p.teamID Please use this query.

Comment: You should store teamIds  instead of team names in your match table. This will save you from [update anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies)

Comment: @HassanALi. tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @apokryfos I need the team names to fetch the related ID to use to query the teams table

Comment: what error you have ?

Comment: @HassanALi "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael why fetch the id using the team name when you can just have the id there to begin with and use that the get the team name if you need it. It's just good practice to have foreight keys refer to the primary key of the other table and not some other unique field (the team names are unique I hope)

Comment: @HassanALi The teams, matches and players are entered into the database using forms. And as such i don't know if i can control or specify whic ID should be for which team. If i then ecide to change the teams, what then happens to the ID stored against a team if fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I have found the issue. In the sql query, I have already called this method `$row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersa);` this has already taken the first row. So calling up that method again in the loop `while ($row_playersa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_playersa)) {
    $playersa[] = $row_playersa;
}` takes up the second record and so on. So to solve the issue, i took out the method in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use AND in your where statement not `&&`, `&&` does something else.

```
  $query_playersa = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE teamID = $matchTeamaID and plyPosition != 'Coach' and plyPosition != 'Assistant Coach'";
```

also change your code to not be vulnerable to injection attacks.  Your site will be powned in hours.

Comment: Made the corrections. Thanks. But still not outputting what i need.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael - to help more you need to show us the exact data model -- the data in the tables -- the output -- and the expected output.

Comment: i have included the table structure and data

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael - you should def store the team id not the team name in the matches table.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael - as a test try the following in your code `$query_playersa = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE teamID = 1 and plyPosition != 'Coach' and plyPosition != 'Assistant Coach'"`  If that does not work then you know the problem is how you process the results not the query itself.

Comment: What i just discovered is that its the first record that should be outputted that disappears. Say the output is supposed to be 1-Michael, 2-john, 3-Jonah. What i get as output is just John and Jonah. Michael disappears.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael are you indexing starting at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: No i don't believe i am.